# ". <file>" syntax vs. "source <file>"

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

In my .bashrc file are these lines

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

I know that `. <file>` syntax is very popular...what is it doing exactly? How might this be different than running

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `.` and `source` are equivalent. In other shells, though, they might be different. For example, traditional `sh` only supports `.`, not `source`.